# Display a value of a powershell array in html

Tags: html, arrays, powershell, output

I have this array:

```
$server = @("value 1", "value 2")
```

and this array, that will be a part of a table:

```
$HtmlHeader= @"
<tr>
<th class="vcenter" colspan="5">$server[$i]</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<th class="colnames">Nome</th>
<th class="colnames">Dimensione (MB)</th>
<th class="colnames">VM</th>
<th class="colnames">Stato VM</th>
<th class="colnames">Data Creazione</th>
</tr>
"@
```

but the output is:

> value 1 value 2[1]

and

> value 1 value 2[2]

How can I fix it, the second array is part of a for cycle and `$i` is defined in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change `$server[$i]` to `$($server[$i])` in the multiline string. However, it's hard to tell, since you didn't show that much of your code.

Comment: it's exactly what i want :) ty!

Answer (score 0):

You can't embed arrays in strings like that.  PowerShell interpets `$server[$i]` as different strings, i.e as `$server` then `[$i]`.  This results in the entire array getting spit out, followed by the value of `$idx`.  I like to use format strings instead of embedding variables directly in strings.  That way I don't have to worry about all the ways embedding variables can go wrong:

```
$HtmlHeader= @"
<tr>
  <th class="vcenter" colspan="5">{0}</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th class="colnames">Nome</th>
  <th class="colnames">Dimensione (MB)</th>
  <th class="colnames">VM</th>
  <th class="colnames">Stato VM</th>
  <th class="colnames">Data Creazione</th>
</tr>
"@ -f $server[$i]
```